# What can be added on a proxy server using TLS v1.3 more secure?

Tags: encryption

i would like to know what can be added to make a proxy server using TLS encryption more secure so that it can bypass censors that are using quantum computational power?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so that it can bypass censors that are using quantum computational power?

There are currently no censors which have this power and it will still be a long time before the techniques are a) established and b) cheap enough to be actually usable for censoring.

Apart from that [work and experiments are underway](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-tls-post-quantum-experiment/) so that future versions of TLS (or maybe extensions to TLS 1.3) can make use of PQC (post quantum cryptography). But this will also likely take more years to get ready and standardized.

This means there is currently no way to use TLS 1.3 to be safe against the attacks you envision. But there is also currently no need since these attacks are not feasible yet and will not be feasible for many years. And there are likely many more important and realistic problems you have to worry about currently - see [this XKCD](https://xkcd.com/538/).